# Is $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z})/\left<([0]_5,[2]_3)\right> \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I know that, using the first isomorphism theorem, I have to define a suprajective homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\ker f = \{([0]_5,[0]_3), \;([0]_5,[1]_3), \;([0]_5,[2]_3)\}$ but I haven’t find it because every correspondence I come up with is not even a function. Any hint?

Comment: A ring homomorphism will induce a group homomorphism. And a group of order 15 doesn't have a group of order 2 as a quotient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that we can find an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z})/(\;([0]_5,[2]_3)\;)$ and $\Bbb Z/ 5\Bbb Z$.  So, the statement that you are trying to show is equivalent to saying that $\Bbb Z/5 \Bbb Z \cong \Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z$.  What is an easy way to see that these two rings (or groups) are **not** isomorphic?

Comment: If $(\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z})/I \cong \mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z} \ncong \mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z} $ then $(\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z})/I \ncong  \mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z} $? Is this because $\cong$ is a equivalence relation?

Comment: Also, as $\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z} \ncong \mathbb{Z}/ 15 \mathbb{Z}$ then $(\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z})/I \ncong \mathbb{Z} / 15 \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @user152985 The answer to all of these questions is yes.

Comment: One last question, I promise! Is ℤ/5ℤ×ℤ/3ℤ ≅ ℤ/15ℤ?

Comment: @user152985 Yes.

Comment: And which isomofism should I define?

Comment: You broke your promise! The map $\phi:\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z / 5\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z / 3 \Bbb Z$ with
$$
\phi([x]_{15}) = ([x]_5,[x]_3)
$$
is an isomorphism.